# Wordpress podcasting with youtube video hosting

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to build a site based on Wordpress for a client. Eventually it will be used to publish videos which could be hosted locally, but to reduce costs it would be nicer if we could host all our videos on somewhere like YouTube or Vimeo.

I'm looking for a plugin or a way of hacking an existing plugin in order to achieve this. The idea is that when we list a new item on the site, users of iTunes / iPod and any other (more) standards compliant podcatcher should be able to view the video.

Ideally I'd like to get away without writing a single line of code, but that may not be possible. The best solution for me is the one which requires the least amount of work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload the video to either Vimeo or YouTube, then re-post it on WordPress, using a plugin to embed the video (here's [one for Vimeo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vimeo-for-wordpress/), [another for YouTube](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-youtube/)).

Any podcatcher should pick it up on the WordPress RSS feed - have I got the right idea here!?